# Set `process.env.commit` on Heroku push

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm using NPM's `scripts.postinstall` to build our application using GulpJS when we push it to Heroku:

```
"postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build --require coffee-script/register"
```

I want to be able to set an environment variable at this time with the value of the commit hash. This will then be referenced in files as a cachebuster, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/index.{{ process.env.commit }}.js"></script>
```

I can use `git-rev` to easily get this value asynchronously but I want it stored on an environment level. **How can I set a custom Node environment variable?**

If I'm going about this the wrong way and there's a better solution please let me know (I can only find methods to set `NODE_ENV` and not the `process.env` object itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I've found is to use the `heroku config` system to set custom environment variables:

```
git = require "git-rev"
exec = require "exec-sync"

gulp.task "commit", ->
  git.long (hash) ->
    exec "heroku config:set COMMIT=#{ hash }"
```

Needs further testing but for now it works (also, because the command is run on the server there's no need to use `heroku config:push`).

Comment: very interesting approach!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this via a `postinstall` script: the `heroku` command won't be available in the build environment. You *can* create your own lightweight deployment script that runs the command on your machine when a successful build occurs however:

```
#!/bin/sh

git push heroku master && heroku config:set COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
```

---

To note, I got confirmation of this from Heroku support directly. This was their response:

> There isn't an installation of heroku toolbelt on the slug compiler. If you need to set an environment variable as part of the push then you'll have to do it on your machine rather than the Heroku compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can now add this metadata with [this labs feature from heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata) !

```
heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata -a <app name>
```